# Showing a modified system of quadratic equations is stable

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-forms, stability, perturbation-theory

I have and $n$ dimensional dynamical system, given by

$\dot{x} = M D(x) P x - \frac{c}{2}x$

$P$ is a full rank $n \times n$ matrix, with $p_{ij} \in [0,c]$, such that $p_{ij}=c-p_{ji}$ for some positive constant $c$ (i.e., $P+P^T=c$). $M$ is an $n \times n$ positive definite, doubly-stochastic matrix. $D(x)$ is a diagonal matrix with the vector $x$ on the diagonals. This equation is defined on the simplex, such that $0<x_i<1$ for all i, and $\sum x_i = 1$.

From previous work I can show that if $M=I$, then this system is neutrally stable, and will oscillate in proportion to the magnitude of the disturbance. However, when $M\ne I$, then this system appears to exhibits global stability, but I am struggling to crack this analytically.

I have tried various approaches to showing either global or local stability. Primarily I've been working on a general Lyapunov function, something of the form $V(x) = \sum x^*_i \log(\frac{x_i^*}{x_i})$, whose derivative is zero if $M=I$, but I cannot find the bounds on $x$ that make this derivative strictly positive when $M \ne I$.

I have also been working on local stability, by showing the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at the solution all have strictly negative real parts. The Jacobian is given by:

$J=M[D(x)P +D(Px)] - I$

But this is somewhat intractable, partly due to not having a closed-form solution for the equilibrium point, and the fact that we are on the simplex, such that the Jacobian always has an eigenvalue of exactly 1.

Alternatively, I have been using an different formulation of the dynamical system, given by

$\dot{x} = D(x) P x - x + (M-I)x$

Which has similar dynamics though a different fixed point solution (though $M$ appears to not need to be full rank here to ensure global stability). The benefit of this second equation is that it is a system of quadratic forms plus a linear operator. I've thus been looking at some work on perturbation theory to try to show that the inclusion of the linear operator effectively damps the oscillations (e.g., work by Brauer and Strauss in the 1970s) but the goal of most work into perturbation theory is to try to show when the perturbations affect the solution. Here I know the solution will change, and instead what I'm interested in is showing the system stabilized by the inclusion of the $(M-I)$ linear operator.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what other approaches to consider or try? Is there something obvious I'm missing? Has anyone seen a similar problem else where?

Thanks!

Comment: Something is strange. Your system, as written, does not preserve the condition $\sum_i x_i=1$ (let's say $P=0$, then it becomes just $\dot x=-x$). It looks like either the equations are wrong or some conditions are missing. What do I not understand here?

Comment: Thanks @fedja. I was being too general with the form for $P$, I've since clarified the problem, noting that we have have $P+P^T=c$ for some positive constant c. Typically I set $c=2$, but this need not be the case. This basically just scales the units of the system.